# Stale element when logging into chrome with MFA - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I understand that the problem is usually because the element is stale. However I am not sure how to fix this in particular. I used wait timers from the browser and from using the `time` module but I am getting no luck as of yet.

I think the problem is that the "Next" button's class seems to always change every second. I have a picture below of what this looks like.

Here is the code:

```
def addemail_blacklist():
    ## code that gets me to the MFA webpage
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#totpPin')))
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#totpPin")
    intermedia_auth.gsotpauth()
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(intermedia_auth.gsotpauth.token)
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#totpNext > div > button > span')))
    time.sleep(3)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#totpNext > div > button > span')))
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span[jsname='V67aGc']")
    im_blacklistsearchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
```

It errors at `im_blacklistsearchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` saying `im_blacklistsearchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Which is weird because that means it found the element yet was not able to do anything with it.

Here is a picture of the error:
[image]

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES YES! I figured out a way around my issue. I decided to use [Action Chains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to get around my issue since it doesn't require having to get a lock on the element. Instead I can use the element I was on last and simply `TAB` over to the `next` button.

Here is the code I used:

```
### previous code from above
im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#totpPin")
    tabtimes = 2
    actions = ActionChains(browser_options.browser)
    actions.move_to_element(im_blacklistaddbutton)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 2)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()
```